# Xpath to get a portion of matched text directly in C#

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xpath

I have a html whose portion looks like this:

```
<li id="SalesRank">
<b>Amazon Best Sellers Rank:</b> 

#841,219 in Music (<a href="http://www.amazon.com/best-sellers-music-albums/zgbs/music/ref=pd_dp_ts_m_1">See Top 100 in Music</a>)

</li>
```

I wanted to extract 841,219 using a single Xpath (Without Linq or processing nodes coming out of the Xpath in a loop)

Obviously, getting to the li element is easy:
`Dim node As HtmlNode = x.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//li[@id=""SalesRank""]")`

After this I am not sure what to put in the Xpath to "extract" the number and have it in `node`

Any ideas would be appreciated. C# or Vb.net can be the language.

Comment: The number is part of the string value of a text node. So you can select `//li[@id = 'SalesRank']/b[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]` to select the text node containing `#841,219 in Music (` but there is no node that contains solely the number.

Comment: Thank you. Does Xpath allow using regular expressions? Can we go that route in one go?

Comment: XPath 2.0 and 3.0 have regular expression support but they operate on string and sequences not on nodes. And I guess you are using the HTML Agility Pack which only supports XPath 1.0.

Comment: FYI, there's an excellent tool for XPath checking [here](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/). You can type the xpath, paste some XML, and it'll highlight matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
substring-before(//li[@id='SalesRank']/text(), 'in')
```

It gets the text before "in"
should return: #841,219

then use substring-after() on the entire result;

```
substring-after(substring-before(//li[@id='SalesRank']/text(), 'in'), '#')
```

which gets the text after '#'
Should return: 841,219.